# How to erase NDEF messages from NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I am working on NFC. I am able to write message on tag. Everything is working fine but when I try to erase the tag, it does not work and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
Tag mytag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
NdefFormatable formatable = NdefFormatable.get(mytag);

if (formatable != null) {
        formatable.connect();
        formatable.format(methodGetMsg());
        formatable.close();
}
```

I'm always getting formatable value `null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to format NFC card using NdefFormatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512204/not-able-to-format-nfc-card-using-ndefformatable)

Answer (score 1):

As your tag already lists the android.nfc.tech.Ndef technology, it is already prepared to store an NDEF message and does not need further formatting. You can simply overwrite (given that the tag is not read-only) any existing NDEF message by using the writeNdefMessage() method of the Ndef object. E.g. to "format" the tag to an empty NDEF message, you could do something like:

```
Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);
ndefTag.writeNdefMessage(new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EMPTY, null, null, null)));
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512204/not-able-to-format-nfc-card-using-ndefformatable)

Comment: Note that this only overwrites the first few bytes of the NDEF message. Using some tricks you can recover almost all of the overwritten NDEF message. To really overwrite all the data it might be a good idea to first write a maximum sized NDEF message to the tag.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck if possible edit answer with your comment. Thank you

Comment: new `NdefMessage` with single record requires API 16 at least. Better go with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20144010/1199132